# Need to simplify date entry in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, date

Every month I need to do a large spreadsheet for billing purposes.

Among other columns I have one start date and another for end date, formatted as dd-mmm.
To enter this date in the spreadsheet for March I type in (for example) 12/3 to get "12-Mar" - the year is not required. All the dates in the March spreadsheet will be in March, (but I prepare the spreadsheet in the following month).

I wanted to simplify the data entry so I only have to specify the month in one cell, and just type in a column with the dd number and have an output column showing the date as dd-mmm.

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

you several options to create the date with formula but I prefer this. Say in A1 put your start date 01/mm/yyyy - always the 1st of every month e.g.:

```
=1/3/2021
```

Might be mm/dd/yyyy if youre in the USA. Its also a good idea to include the year so that leap days would be handled correctly. Now in your dd input column (say C1 to C1000) simply data capture 1 or 2 or 31 or whichever day of the month. Now in start date put

```
=$A$1+C1-1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Mobus` answer is a great example of thinking outside the normal Excel aspects of the problem:  basically, he expects the first date of the month be entered somewhere, perhaps the first entry in the column, and then, since any other day of the month entered is the date of the month, if you add it to the first day and subtract off one day so you don't double count the first day (the date entered also includes the first day, so it would be counted in that first entry AND in the new entry), then you have the value for that entry's date.

Quite nice, and done along the lines of using algebra to simplify your problem before figuring out what Excel needs to do.

However, it does not cover all the possible entries. For instance, you use the example of entering 12 March as the first entry. So it would fail. NOT a problem if you can re-jig your data entry, or if you set aside a ell somewhere to enter the 1 March date, 1 April, etc., and then use that for the reference you add the entry to and subtract 1 from. Either works and then his very straightforward approach works.

But if you prefer to do as you are doing now, not changing the nature of your data entry (after all, 1 March may not be a date you need entered this month, so it might be awkward...) and not changing the form of the spreadsheet to include a way (cell, Named Range, etc.) to have the first day of the month available to the calculation, there is another way, one built into Excel for this purpose.

It is to use the function `DATEVALUE()`. It takes as string that has date information and returns the proper Excel-style date. That would make it have the year as well, but simply format the output column to display "dd-mmm" and you have the display you desire.

Assume the entry column is column A and the first cell in it, A1, is the first date entered. You enter it as you say in the question (and format it as you desire), but since it is taken as a date by Excel, it will include the year, regardless of how you display it. It will then be your reference for obtaining the month and year for Excel to use in the formula. You will get the date from the data entry cell:

```
=DATEVALUE(  A2  & "/" &  MONTH($A$1)  & "/" &  YEAR($A$1)  )
```

The formula builds the string by taking the entered day value, attaching the `/` looking to  the first cell, A1, for the month value and attaching it, then attaching another `/` and finally looking A1 for the year. That string is then presented to `DATEVALUE()` which turns it into a "proper" date. It displays as you formatted so you have it.

Note that it never looks to that first entry for the day value, just month and year, so even if it is a random day of the month, like 12 March, ALL the other dates calculate and display properly.

All done as you are currently doing, just entering the 12/3, say, in the first entry cell, then the one or two digits for each day value in all the other cells. Neither your work habits, nor those of other users have to change. No training, no complaints, no reorganizing the spreadsheet.